# Cannot see Nexus 6P for debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-debugging, nexus-6p

I'm using Windows 10, a Dell XPS 13, and v1.4.1 of Android Studio.  I have SDK Tools 24.4.1 installed as well as Google USB Driver 11.
#
On the phone I have USB debugging enabled and can see the device in File Explorer (i.e. documents, pictures, etc.).

But the device never shows up using `adb devices`, nor in Android Studio.

I've never had this much trouble getting an Android device debugging before, but I don't know if it's Marshmallow or the Nexus 6P that's to blame. More importantly, I've no idea what to do at this point to get it debugging.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this exact problem and solved it by downloading (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) and installing the Google USB Driver by hand.

Before I did that, I tried installing it from the Android SDK Manager which did not work. The package installed without error but my Device Manager showed a failure for an ADB Interface device.

After downloading/extracting the zip file from the above link, I updated the failed ADB Interface driver in Device Manager and now I can see and use my phone in both Android Studio and from the command line with adb.

I'm assuming that you have also enabled USB Debugging on your phone as detailed here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice

Comment: Yep, manual installation of the Google USB driver was required. Dunno if that's a Windows 10 thing or what, but it did the trick.

Comment: My problem is that I can not even see the Android device under Device Manager.

Comment: can you edit this answer into two steps? 1. enable usb debugging 2. follow android link to add the driver.

Comment: I can confirm that this works after trying several things. A couple of notes: You need to be in the OS, not in fastboot mode. Of course you need to have USB debugging enabled. And lastly, download the standalone USB drivers (do NOT use the ones that are in the extras folder in the Android SDK directory) and update the ABD interface driver manually.

Answer (score 12):

I spent a lot of time with this problem. You need to manually download the driver here (http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Then go to "Devices and Printers", right-click on "MTP", and choose properties.

Click "ADB interface", then click "Properties"

Go to "Driver" tab and update driver with the file you just downloaded. (Make sure you unzip them first)

Comment: You have to click "Change settings" in Properties update the driver. (I'm on Windows 10)

Comment: Also, I had to uninstall (and check "delete driver") before MTP showed up in Devices and Printers.

Comment: On my Windows 7 laptop, accessing `Devices and Printers` -> `MTP` didn't allow me to update the driver. Instead I went to `Device Manager` -> right click `MTP` -> `update driver`

Comment: That link no longer seems to provide a download. The link is there but it does not work.

Answer (score 5):

I would try to do the following:
1. switch between USB configuration modes: MTP and PTP.
   Enter Developer options and find there the 'Select USB Configuration' option.
2. replace the USB cable - sometimes it does the trick.
3. Try to connect your device to a different computer/OS (try it on a Linux platform)
4. Check in Device Manager if there are any driver issues (a yellow bang)
5. reinstall drivers.

Comment: It connects to my Mac ok using the same cable (that came with the 6P), so apparently I need the Nexus 6P-specific driver?  Although you'd think the Google USB driver would work on Google phones...

Comment: I had to restart my Nexus 6P, then it asked me if I wanted to allow the debug certificate.

Comment: for suggestion #1, switching to anything i believe will work.  For instance, I switch to Charging only from MTP, and then the debugging prompt to allow my PC came up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be two questions. Firstly , you should enable USB  Debugging mode in your device. just reference http://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm.
Then if it is not ok , you should download Nexus 6P's driver and install it. reference http://www.technobuzz.net/install-google-nexus-6p-usb-drivers/. Good luck.

Comment: I don't know that I can trust the driver referred to by TechnoBuzz.  Going directly to Huawei.com an searching for drivers yields none.

Comment: Maybe you can download HiSuite for try. This mobile manager is developed by HuaWei. http://consumer.huawei.com/minisite/HiSuite_en/

Answer (score -1):

This is one of the oddest hacks I have ever seen, but it works. On a Nexus 6P, you open Settings, System, About phone, and scroll to Build number at the bottom.

Click Build number 7 times.

That is how you enable Developer options, and thus USB debugging on a Nexus 6P.

No special magic needed after that.  It just shows up as an available device (in Visual Studio anyway):

[image]