# Galaxy S6 ADB upgraded to Marshmallow stops working

Tags: android

I have been developing an app using a Galaxy S6 with Android 5.1.1. The USB driver worked fine getting from Windows 10 ( Android Studio 2.1 ) to my phone. I could debug with no problem. My phone was upgraded to Android 6 ( Marshmallow ). I no longer can debug. I have been assuming this is a problem with the Samsung driver, but I am not sure. Is their a workaround for this?

Comment: check your developer mode is activated or not

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747550/cannot-see-nexus-6p-for-debugging) link

Comment: Yes. Developer mode was active. I troubleshooted the issue with Samsung Chat support. They instructed me to run in "safe mode" to see if it would work and it did. When I rebooted back to regular mode it broke again. I found the solution to be  "Go to the Push Notificatino entry" for "Charging" and set the phone to "Connect to a Media Device" and it now works. Apparently, this was originally set as the default value, but when the phone was upgraded, it lost its default. Setting it back to "Connect as a Media Device" and checking "Do this Always" fixes the problem.